# Quick / Built-in method for detecting table change in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is there a quick and easy way of telling if a table has changed in SQL Server? (I'm using SQL Server 2005). Something like an incrementing ID somewhere that updates on each INSERT, DELETE or UPDATE that I can keep track of. I noticed there is a sys.objects.modify_date column for each table, but I don't think it's quite what I want because the docs say:

> Date the object was last modified by
>   using an ALTER statement. If the
>   object is a table or a view,
>   modify_date also changes  when a
>   clustered index on the table or view
>   is created or altered.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29693448/sql-server-find-out-when-a-table-was-renamed/29695037#29695037

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/09/sql-server-find-last-date-time-updated-for-any-table/) from Pinal Dave. From the link:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS DatabaseName, last_user_update,*
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE database_id = DB_ID( 'AdventureWorks')
AND OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('test')
```