# SQL Server Find Out When a Table Was Renamed?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to find out when a table was renamed? (as a primary question)
And if possible which user did it?

Comment: I think there is no such `view` or `log table`. I guess the best changes you have is to search for the command in the `transaction log` file - you may  be able to identify the user, too (if your database is running under `FULL` recovery model).

Comment: which version of sql server are you using?

Comment: To log any future renaming of tables, In SQL Server 2008 and above you can use [Database Audit Specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx).

Answer (score 8):

You can try this:

```
SELECT Name, modify_date, * FROM sys.all_objects
WHERE Name = 'Table name'
```

Comment: nice idea. if there were no other changes in the table schema after the rename and you know the name of the table, this would work . +1